# Значение между тэгами

Tags: html

День добрый.

есть строка
`STRING = "<html><body><div><a>Текст</a></div><body></html>"`

Каким образом можно вытащить значение между тегами `<а>`

Comment: исопльзуй javascript, у него для работы со строками есть много полезных методов. Тебе подойдут slice или substring. Можно извратиться и сделать с помощью split.
Подробнее почитай тут http://javascript.ru/String

Comment: Вас интересует общий алгоритм (хе-хе) или реализация на конкретном ЯП?

Comment: Скорее сам алгоритм

Comment: Алгоритм здесь - конечный автомат.

Comment: что хоть за ЯП?

    $('<html><body><div><a>Текст</a></div><body></html>').find('a').text()

Comment: Выражение - выражению рознь! Допустим при присутствии атрибута `href` это уже будет другое выражение! ЯП уточнить не мешало бы!

Comment: Нужно отсекать тэги с внешней стороны.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем и целом есть 2 способа:

1. **Научный**: пишем/берем полномасштабный парсер. Идеально подойдет нечто вроде [SAX парсера](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_API_for_XML). Правда, есть сомнения в well-form'ности куска, поскольку в приведенном примере тег `<body>` не закрывается...
2. **Дубовый**: ищем вхождение подстрок `<a>` и `</a>`, то что находится между ними будет наше искомое значение. Ясен пень, что дубовый способ не всегда может сработать - скажем если внутри тега `<a>` есть другие вложенности и проч. сюрпризы.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html><body><div><a>(.+)</a></div></body></html>
```

вот вам регулярка для java)

Answer (score 0):

Как насчет такого варианта?

```
(?<=<a>).*(?=</a>)
```

P.S. У вас в примере тег <a> не закрывается: `<a>Текст<a>`.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте регулярное выражение.

Comment: regexp годится ТОЛЬКО в том случае, когда анализируемая строка имеет фиксированную структуру и html-код корректен. Для полноценного разбора html-тэгов нужно делать конечный автомат или парсер.